# Can't make PTRACE_SEIZED(ptrace request) work

Tags: c, linux

I'm playing with ptrace and trying to get register system calls value(orig_rax) of my process, I have no problem doing it with `PTRACE_TRACEME` request(tracer/tracee), then I tried with `PTRACE_ATTACH`(attach the process at runtime) and got no problem, but now I try with `PTRACE_SEIZED` and I have some problem to get those system call, I just cannot parse properly my process.
I know that the difference between `PTRACE_ATTACH` and `PTRACE_SEIZED` are that with seized I need to stop myself the process(I use `PTRACE_INTERRUPT for that`).
Below is my code: all printf and `if (i == 3) break;` after the `while(1)` are for debug purpose.
So what I'm simply trying to do is to parse my program by attaching my process with `PTRACE_SEIZED` request (from ptrace function) and extract all system calls(orig_rax register) done (more particularly isolate those done with my `execl` function,which call /bin/ls, in my `main`).
When I run my code all ptrace_function return 0 and the process received well the stopping signal(`WIFSTOPPED(status) == true`), but rip register seem not to change (sometimes it change and I get some correct orig_rax value only once and after nothing I get always the same value)
I also tried with `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` instead of `PTRACE_SYSCALL`, and it worked only once in my `while(1)`, after RIP is always the same value.
(I did some research on google and found no example of process parsing with PTRACE_SEIZED, i'm a begginer with ptrace, kernel, signal stuff, so maybe my miscomprehension come from here).
Any help, examples, helpful links are appreciated. I hope I'm clear enough.
Thanks.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int             seized_process(pid_t pid)
{
        int                                             status;
        struct user_regs_struct regs;
        int                                             pt_ret;
        siginfo_t                               siginfo;
        int                                     i = 0;

        pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, pid, NULL, NULL);
        printf("PTRACE_SEIZE ret: %d\n", pt_ret);
        printf("parent :%d \n", pid);

        while (1) {
                if (i == 3)
                        break;
                pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_INTERRUPT, pid, NULL, NULL);
                printf("PTRACE_INTERRUPT ret: %d\n", pt_ret);
                waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
                printf("waitpid status: %d\n", status);
                if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
                        printf("process received stopping signal(Group-stop)\n");

                pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, NULL, &siginfo);
                printf("PTRACE_SIGINFO ret: %d, sig num: %d, si_code: %d \n",
                                pt_ret, siginfo.si_signo, siginfo.si_code);
                pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);
                printf("PTRACE_GETREGS ret: %d rip %#llx, orig_rax: %#llx,"
                           " rax : %#llx\n", pt_ret, regs.rip, regs.orig_rax,
                           regs.rax);

                pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL,
                                WSTOPSIG(status));
                printf("PTRACE_SYSCALL ret : %d\n", pt_ret);

                if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                        printf("WIFEXITED(status)\n");
                        break ;
                }
                else if (WSTOPSIG(status)) {
                        printf("WSTOPSIG(status)\n");
                }
                printf("\n---------------------\n");
                i++;
        }
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pid_t   child;

        child = fork();
        printf("fork value: %d \n", child);
        if (child == 0) {
                printf("child\n");
                execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
        }
        else {
                seized_process(child);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `ptrace` man page ...

Under the section for `PTRACE_SEIZE`, we have:

> Unlike PTRACE_ATTACH, PTRACE_SEIZE does **not**   stop   the   process.

Under the `PTRACE_TRACEME`, we have:

> For requests other than PTRACE_ATTACH, PTRACE_SEIZE, PTRACE_INTERRUPT, and PTRACE_KILL, the tracee must be stopped.

So, for the tracer to be able to examine the tracee's registers, etc. the tracee must be stopped. But, `PTRACE_SEIZE` [by itself] doesn't do that.

So, you'd need to use `PTRACE_ATTACH` or do something else in addition to `PTRACE_SEIZE` to stop the process before trying to examine its registers or memory.

When you think about it, there isn't much value to getting a snapshot of a process that is *running* because you'd wouldn't get an atomic view of it. You'd be "racing" against it [just like two threads racing on a global value]. That is, (e.g.) you grab `eax`, then memory, but they might have already changed values between the `ptrace` calls.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I know i have to stop my process(tracee), that's why i use: `pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_INTERRUPT, pid, NULL, NULL);`

In your loop, you do `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` to stop the process. Then, you grab the data, print it, and loop.

But, in your loop, you never do anything to resume the tracee (e.g. `PTRACE_CONT`), so once the first iteration of your loop is done, the traced process *remains* stopped. It only resumes *after* you exit your loop and do the `PTRACE_DETACH`.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Yes. `PTRACE_SYSCALL` *will* resume the traced process. But, the tracer's `ptrace` call will return *immediately*. Then, at the loop top, you do another `PTRACE_INTERRUPT`.

This means that the traced process will be scheduled to run, but might get stopped [again] before it gets the chance to run. (i.e. the tracer and tracee are "racing"). This is probably close to what you're seeing.

Also, I'd increase the number of iterations in the tracer as 3 is a bit small to see much.

Try doing the `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` *before* the loop. This makes `PTRACE_SEIZE` followed by `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` the moral equivalent of `PTRACE_ATTACH`.

Then, the loop of: `waitpid`, print, `PTRACE_SYSCALL` should work without racing. Having `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` in the same loop as `PTRACE_SYSCALL` [sort of] defeats the purpose of `PTRACE_SYSCALL`.

Using `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` [after the initial one] only makes sense if you do `PTRACE_CONT`.

However, when doing `PTRACE_SYSCALL`, it might make sense to loop on the `waitpid` with `WNOHANG`. If you don't get a stop within a reasonable amount of time, that means the target isn't doing any syscalls. At that point, you might issue the `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` then, to force the stop so you can examine state.

With `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` above the loop, try `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` to reduce the granularity.

`ls` is a bit opaque as far as single stepping goes (e.g. you'd probably have to install the debuginfo package to get a symbol table).

Try writing a simple target/tracee program where you precisely control the behavior. You can generate a full disassembly of it. And, then match the addresses against the `rip` values you get back from single step tracing.

Comment: I know i have to stop my process(tracee), that's why i use: ```pt_ret = ptrace(PTRACE_INTERRUPT, pid, NULL, NULL);``` and that's also why in my code i verify that with ```if (WIFSTOPPED(status))```, which give me true (from the man: ```Ptrace-stopped  tracees  are  reported  as  returns  with  pid greater than 0 and WIFSTOPPED(status) true.``` and ```If tracee was attached using PTRACE_SEIZE, group-stop is indicated by PTRACE_EVENT_STOP: status>>16 == PTRACE_EVENT_STOP``` which is the value i got(since my wait status is 8390015).

Comment: To answer to your update, from the man: `Another group of commands makes the ptrace-stopped tracee run.  They have the form: ptrace(cmd, pid, 0, sig); where  cmd  is PTRACE_CONT, PTRACE_LISTEN, PTRACE_DETACH, PTRACE_SYSCALL,  PTRACE_SINGLESTEP,   PTRACE_SYSEMU,   or PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP.` If i understand well(i doubt about it) my PTRACE_SYSCALL make the tracee run (resume ?). I also try `PTRACE_LISTEN`(from the man: ```Restart the stopped tracee, but prevent it from executing.```) which seemed to be the correct way to resume the process but it didn't work.

Comment: To answer your update #2: you are right, it worked well. Thanks a lot for your explications, it's a lot clearer.